# PaloaltoのL2設定について

Tags: network

Paloaltoの設定で質問があります。
DMZにポートを８ポートアサインしてサーバを直接接続を行いたいのですが
接続されたノード間の接続ができません。（pingも通らず）添付キャプチャは暫定的にL2SWへ伸ばして対応しているためポート6のみUPですが本来は１－５のポートにノードを接続して構築したいと考えています。
またDMZには10.xxx.xxx.254/24のアドレスを付与しており
ノードからそのアドレスへはpingが通ります。
ethernet1-8までをL2スイッチのように動作させたいのですがどの部分を編集する必要があるのでしょうか。
お力お貸しいただければと思います。

[image: 設定画面キャプチャ]